# How to adjust an image and make it responsive - HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a website: [click here to see it](https://www.b3lieve.com.mx/), and in the hero section, I put an confetti image and added like a parallax effect.
In the desktop view, it looks "good" but not perfect at all because there is a space left at the top and in the bottom. Similarly, in the mobile views, it looks weird and pixelated with the same space.

[Desktop view with blank spaces at top and bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzJvi.jpg)

[Mobile view, where it's impossible see the confetti image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHc50.jpg)

I tried many things to fix it but couldn't. I'm hoping someone knowledgeable in css can explain why this is happening and how I fix it.

Comment: I visited the website but it looks fine to me in both desktop and mobile. Any more details about how the situation occurred or may be reproduced?

Comment: This is a valid question, I don't know why the people or staff at StackOverflow,  give a negative mark. In this way, I think people will hesitate to ask questions. Or StackOverflow is only for scholars or highly experienced computer professionals. Not  for the learners.

Answer (score 0):

The top and bottom space is caused by the padding in  element:

```
padding: 125px 0 var(--section-padding);
```

Since the background with the confetti is placed in a `<div>` inside that `<section>` element, the image appears after that space.

You should either move that padding to the `<div class="hero-confeti">` element, or move the background image to the `<section>` element.

Comment: I've tried it, but didn't work 